# Django: query all items that have a foreign key point to them

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

In Django, how can I select all objects of class 'A' that have an object of class B that points to them? For example, if the database contains these three entries of class 'A':

```
A, named "one"
A, named "two"
A, named "three"
```

And two entries of class B:

```
B, points to "two"
B, points to "three"
```

I want to select classes "two" and "three" of type A.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(b = b)
```

where b is an object of class `B` and the `b=` refers to the lowercase model name which you want to query the reverse relationship.

Read more on [lookups that span relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). It covers how to do a reverse lookup on models' ForeignKey attributes

Edit:

If you are looking for all objects which *do not* have any `ForeignKey` objects pointing to them, you can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) and [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

```
a_qs = A.objects.exclude(b__isnull = True)
```

Comment: The right hand side of the filter expression isn't any particular object though, it's simply that some object exists. Something to the effect of: `a_qs = A.objects.filter(where b exists)`

Comment: You mean get me all objects which have some foreign key associated with them ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But not all objects of type B. The objects that the type Bs point to.

Comment: Ah ha, the edit worked perfectly! Thanks, Karthikr! However, one thing I should point out is that using exclude and __isnull selects all 'A' objects that DO have ForeignKeys that point to them. Using False would select items that are NOT pointed to.

Comment: should this not be `b_set__isnull`. The default related name of 'my_name' is 'my_name_set', so unless you write in `B`: `a=models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b')` using `b` for the backwards relationship will not work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(b__a__isnull=False).distinct()
```

It gives only the objects of A which has a B object pointing to it. Use `a__isnull=False` to check whether a ForeignKey exists. If it does, it can, by definition, only point to A.  Duplicates are removed with `distinct()`.

When a `related_name` parameter has been set, e.g.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b_list')
```

this worked:

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(b_list__a__isnull=False).distinct()
```