# How to filter objects in Django that do not have any other objects pointing to them?

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm using Django 1.7.1.

I have a set of models similar to the following structure:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class ItemTypeOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ref = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class ItemTypeTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ref = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class ItemTypeThree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ref = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006765/django-query-all-items-that-have-a-foreign-key-point-to-them) I know that is possible to use the orm to filter objects that are not pointed by a specific class of objects. In my situation it would be something like:

```
filtered = Group.objects.exclude(itemtypeone__isnull=False,
                                 itemtypetwo__isnull=False,
                                 itemtypethree__isnull=False)
```

My goal is to achieve the same result using the orm without the need to explicitly informing the 'reverse relations', something similar to (pseudocode follows):

```
filtered = Group.objects.exclude(gereric_reverse_relations_exp__isnull=False)
```

Is this possible to be achieved using django orm?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you could make yourself a helper method i quess, but probably there is some better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inspect all models to find out which ones have a foreign key on `Group` and dynamically build the query. Use the model's `_meta` `get_all_related_objects()` to get a list of `RelatedObject` for your `Group` model:

```
>>> related = Group._meta.get_all_related_objects()
>>> print related 
[<RelatedObject: app:itemtypeone related to group>, <RelatedObject: app:itemtypetwo related to van>, <RelatedObject: app:itemtypethree related to group>]
```

Then build your lookups:

```
>>> excludes = dict(("%s__isnull" % ro.get_accessor_name(), False) for ro in related)
```

And execute your query:

```
>>> filtered = Group.objects.exclude(**excludes)
```

(warning: mostly untested code, might need some tweaking).

Comment: Only needed a small adjustment: use ro.name instead of ro.get_accessor_name().

Thanks once again!